# Dropdown is not populated when making HTTP call to get values from nested component

Tags: angular

I have a component which uses a service to get data from an API. This service and component works as I can successfully display this data on a page in a table. I now am trying to use this component inside of another component to populate a drop down form control. Unfortunately, this drop down is not populated.

When debugging this it looks like an async issue as I can see the data being displayed in my console (using `console.log()` for debugging). I can also see other `console.log()` statements placed before and after displaying but both output their values *before* the nested component is called.

**Calling Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Debugging code
    console.log('Before this.playerComponent.getPlayers()');

    // Nested component that gets the data from a service
    this.playerComponent.getPlayers();
    this.players = this.playerComponent.players;

    // Debugging code
    console.log('After this.playerComponent.getPlayers()');
}
```

**PlayerComponent (Nested Component)**

```
getPlayers(): void {
    this.playerService.getPlayers().subscribe(
        players => {
            this.players = players;
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
}
```

**playerService**

```
getPlayers(): Observable<IPlayer[]> {
    return this.http.get<IPlayer[]>(`${this.url}/players`).pipe(
        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

**HTML component**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="player">Player</label>
    <select id="player" #season class="custom-select" formControlName="playerid">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Player (required)</option>
        <option *ngFor='let player of players' value="{{player.playerid}}">{{player.player}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot showing the console with my debugging output:

[image]

So my questions is, do I need to change this code to wait until after the HTTP request returns data? Or do I need to change the code so it reacts when the data is returned?

Comment: `getPlayers` is asynchronous, so `change the code so it reacts when the data is returned`.

Comment: If in `ngOnInit` `this.playerComponent` is child component, I would do `ngAfterViewInit` instead `ngOnInit`. And yes, you have to "wait" for data, that is not solution to call `http` and assume that it will come.

Comment: @muradm using `ngAfterViewInit` did not seem to change the results

Comment: @Pengyy - That's what I am trying to figure out how to do. I thought that when `this.players` was populated with the player data it would have updated the view accordingly. So far Google has led me to trying to use a Promise instead of an observable but I didn't get better results.

Comment: @JohnConde, yeah, it won't, since you are calling `httpClient` and not "waiting" for response, so it does not matter. However, whenever child component is used via `@ViewChild()`, normally it can be referred on `ngAfterViewInit`, not earlier. See the answer below, how I would do data thing normally.

Comment: @JohnConde Promise and Observable both will work. Take Observable as example, you just need to change `getPlayers`(*component one*) to return Observable in order to subscribe to it in both your inside & outside component.

Comment: What my issue looks like it I am trying to manage the player logic all in the player component but what I need to do is call the player service directly from the host component (the calling component in my question) so i can subscribe to it properly.

Comment: Simple: before subscribe playerService.getPlayer(), make a this.players=null (or this.players=[])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managing data is hard between components. Now days, using Angular, it is good practice to separate ***Smart Component*** from ***Presentation Component***.

Basically, Smart Component is responsible for managing data and shipping it to presentation component, where Presentation Component only responsible for displaying the data.

Here is good explanation on subject.

- [Angular Architecture - Smart Components vs Presentational Components](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/)

Example:

**Calling component (Will be our Smart Component)**

```
players = null;

constructor(private playerService: PlayerService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.playerService.getPlayers().subscribe(players => this.players = players);
}
```

**Calling component HTML**

```
<app-players [players]="players"></app-players>
```

**Players Component (Presentation component)**

```
@Input() players;
```

**Players Component HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="player">Player</label>
<select id="player" #season class="custom-select" formControlName="playerid">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Player (required)</option>
    <option *ngFor='let player of players' value="{{player.playerid}}">{{player.player}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Following this practice (pouring data from parent component to child component) makes life easier.

Comment: I think you've sent me down the right path. I'll hack away at this and return with the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Observable` instead of access the instance variable. It always ensures that you have data once the async call is completed.

Make following changes

#### PlayerComponent (Nested Component)

```
getPlayers(): void {
    return this.playerService.getPlayers(); //<-- return players Observable 
}
```

#### Calling Component

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Debugging code
    console.log('Before this.playerComponent.getPlayers()');

    // Nested component that gets the data from a service
    this.playerComponent.getPlayers().subscribe(
    players =>  this.players = players);
}
```

If you want the players in nested component as well, you can use the same function getPlayers() and subscribe it.

> Note : code was written in stackoverflow editor directly so there could be some typo or syntactical error. Please correct yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Why you have coded it this way you should have model only in one component and the child can execute that in its own ngOnInit method if you want the data from child to be available on parent use eventemitter to notify the parent about the availability of players array from child once we service returns response and then reinitialize the array of parent component via notification by eventemitter.